# Prove $(U+W)/U$ and $W/(U\cap W)$ are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, quotient-spaces

> Let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$; then $U$ is a subspace of $U+V$ and $U\cap W$ is a subspace of $W$. Prove that the **quotient spaces** $$(U+W)/U \ \ \text{and}\ \ W/(U\cap W)$$ are isomorphic.
>    *Hint:* A coset of $U$ in (U+W) has the form $w+U$, and $w_1+U \equiv w_2 +U$ iff $w_1-w_2\in U$. (equivalence classes or coset)

The following is my work:

We have to prove $\phi: (U+W)/U \xrightarrow[]{\phi}W/(U\cap W)$ is isomorphism.

Note: $\tilde{x} = x+U$ mans $\{v=x+u : u\in U\}$, which is a set.

1. **onto**: For each $x\in W$, the coset of $(U\cap W)$ that contains $x$ is $\tilde{x}=x+(U\cap W)$.
   Since $x\in W$, so $\tilde{x}=w+(U\cap W)$. Since $(U+W)\subset U$, we prove onto.
2. **one-to-one**: Suppose $\tilde{x}_1=w_1+U$ and $\tilde{x}_2=w_2+U$ with $w_1-w_2\notin U$ (i.e. two different coset) such that $\phi(\tilde{x}_1)\equiv \phi(\tilde{x}_2)$.
   Suppose $\phi(\tilde{x}_i) \equiv w+(U\cap W)$ where $i=1,2$.

Now I am stuck here.

> 1. How to show $\phi^{-1}(\phi(\tilde{x}_i)) $ points to the same coset such that we reach a contradiction?     My problem is I cannot quite understand what the map does here and how to map; therefore, I cannot continue it.
> 2. How to show $\phi^{-1}$ is isomorphism? Since $(U\cap W)\subset U$, I have no idea how does "onto" hold.

How to fix them?

Comment: It would be better to consider the map $W \to (U+W)/U$, $w \mapsto w+U$, and prove that it is surjective with kernel $U\cap W$

Comment: You haven't even defined what $\phi$ is, so how do you expect to prove that it is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler using the homomorphism theorem. The map
$$
\alpha\colon W\to (U+W)/U
\qquad
\alpha(x)=x+U
$$
is a linear map. Its kernel is $U\cap W$ and therefore we get an isomorphism
$$
(U+W)/U\cong W/\ker\alpha=W/(U\cap W)
$$
by the main homomorphism theorem.

Without the homomorphism theorem, you can directly define
$$
\beta\colon W/(U\cap W)\to U+W/U
$$
by declaring $\beta(w+U\cap W)=w+U$

You have to check that

1. $\beta$ is well defined: if $w_1+U\cap W=w_2+U\cap W$, then $w_1+U=w_2+U$
2. $\beta$ is injective: if $w+U=0+U$ then $w+U\cap W=0+U\cap W$
3. $\beta$ is surjective: this is the easy part, because $u+w+U=\beta(w+U\cap W)$

Comment: I am not quite familiar with this approach; since the textbook does not cover homomorphism theorems (just a undergraduate linear algebra(maybe not a first course)).  If just using definition of isomorphism and quotient space; how to prove it?